# Support annotations not found by androidJavadocs task

Tags: android, annotations, javadoc

During execution of task `:androidJavadocs` I'm getting:

```
javadoc: warning - Class NonNull not found.
```

It looks like support annotations from Android are not found even though compilation is ok.

How to get rid of such warnings?

Comment: Can you please copy here that part of your gradle file?

Comment: @Blehi https://github.com/allegro/slinger/blob/master/build.gradle and https://github.com/allegro/slinger/blob/master/slinger/build.gradle